# How to store in different lists?

Tags: python, list, slice

I have two list as follows

```
 l1 = [2,4,3]
l2 = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

I want to make a three lists like `[4,5]`, `[6,7,8,9]` and `[10,11,12]` from `l2`. I can do it different way but I need to do by using loop.

I already tried something as follows:

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
a.append(l2[0:2])
b.append(l2[2:4+2])
c.append(l2[4+2:])
```

I want it using loop where element of `l1` will be the size of each new list.

Answer (score 1):

For the following code, the resulting lists are stored in the "result" list.

The variable "counter" is used to indicate the starting index and "x" is each element in l1, so l2[counter:counter+x] can get the list that you want. This may not be the shortest code but I guess it is clear and concise. Hope that helps!

```
l1 = [2,4,3]
l2 = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

result = []
counter = 0
for x in l1:
   result += [l2[counter:counter+x]]
   counter += x

print(result)
[[4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension with islice

```
from itertools import islice
l1 = [2,4,3]
l2 = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
il2 = iter(l2)
l = [list(islice(il2, x)) for x in l1]
print(l)
# [[4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

**Performance**

Testing five methods posted here using timeit on the dataset l1, l2 in Jupyter notebook, with libraries preloaded.
Pok Fung Chan post had fastest method.

```
Method 1. pok fung chan -- 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.17 µs per loop
Method 2: ncica         -- 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.93 µs per loop
Method 3: darrylg       -- 100000 loops, best of 3: 4.02 µs per loop
Method 4: RoadRunner    -- 100000 loops, best of 3: 6.38 µs per loop
Method 5: Rakeesh       -- 100000 loops, best of 3: 8.76 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it on this way:

```
l1 = [2,4,3]
l2 = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
l2_ = l2.copy()
result = []

for item in l1:
    result.append(l2_[:item])
    del l2_[:item]

a,b,c = result
print (a)
print (b)
print (c)
```

output:

```
[4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9]
[10, 11, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehinsion and `list.pop`

**Ex:**

```
l1 = [2,4,3]
l2 = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
print([[l2.pop(0) for _ in range(i)] for i in l1])
```

**Output:**

```
[[4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `l2` to a `collections.deque` to allow O(1) pops from the left using `popleft()`.

```
from collections import deque

l1 = [2,4,3]
l2 = deque([4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])

result = [[l2.popleft() for _ in range(x)] for x in l1]

print(result)
# [[4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```